# Не правильно вычисляет C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++

*Задание*:

> Задан двумерный массив С из 2-х строк и 4-х столбцов. Составить программу, которая организует одномерный массив, каждый элемент которого есть количество отрицательных элементов исходного массива в строке. Вычислить сумму элементов полученного массива.

```
//Sedyolkin Yuriu Alekseevich 4103
//lab5
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <cstdlib>
#include <math.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <locale.h>

using namespace std;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    setlocale(0, "");
    system("cls");
    int i, j, k;
    double s = 0;
    int a[2][4];
    int b[2];
    for (i = 0;i < 2;i++)
    {
        for (j = 0;j < 4;j++)
        {
            cout << "Введи a[" << i << "," << j << "]=";
            cin >> a[i][j];
            cout << endl;
        }
    }
    for (i = 0;i < 2;i++)
    {
        for (j = 0;j < 4;j++)
        {
            cout << a[i][j] << "  ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    for (i = 0;i < 2;i++)
    {
        k = 0;
        for (j = 0;j < 4;j++)
            if (a[i][j] < 0)
                k++;
        b[j] = k;
        cout << b[j] << endl;

    }
    for (j = 0;j < 2;j++)
        s = b[j] + s;
    if (s == 0)
        cout << "Нет отрицательных значений в массиве а""\n";
    else
        cout << "Сумма элементов преобразованного массива: " << s << endl;
system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

Не правильно вычисляется сумма элементов второго массива в конце программы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас имеется опечатка. В этом цикле в качестве индекса массива `b` должна использоваться переменная `i`, а не `j`

```
for (i = 0;i < 2;i++)
{
    k = 0;
    for (j = 0;j < 4;j++)
        if (a[i][j] < 0)
            k++;
    b[j] = k;
    ^^^^
    cout << b[j] << endl;
            ^^^^
}
```

И нет никакого смысла объявлять переменную s, как имеющую тип double.

```
double s = 0;
```

Объявите ее, как имеющую тип `int`.

И можно следующие заголовки убрать

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
```